# HttpClient post not completing inside resolve guard unless piped through `take(1)`

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-httpclient, angular6

I have an Angular application with routing and a resolve guard. The resolve guard is asynchronous and returns an observable returned from `HttpClient.post` - problem is, the AJAX request completes but the observable doesn't, and therefore the resolver never finishes its work, and the page never gets displayed. However when I pipe the result through `take(1)` it does complete and it works fine. My question is why? Isn't `HttpClient.post` supposed to complete after the AJAX request returns ok (`200 OK`)?

Here's the code of my resolver:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyDataResolver implements Resolve<MyData> {
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
    : MyData | Observable<MyData> | Promise<MyData> {
    return this.svc.getData().pipe(take(1)); // <-- Why is take(1) necessary here??
}

constructor(private svc: MyService) { }

}
```

Here's the service method that calls `post`:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class MyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getData(): Observable<MyData> {
    return this.http.post('/api/data'), {}).pipe(
      map((resp: { data: SomeData }) => resp.data),
      map(r => convertSomeDataToMyData(r)));
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what does your service `getData()` method look like? does it return `http.get/post...` observable directly or maybe some other observable?

Comment: It's pretty much a simple post, piped through two maps... Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: yes, that sounds strange. `http.post` should complete once response is gotten from server. can you also show `convertSomeDataToMyData()` method?

Comment: I have the answer, it is my error of course. it is due to an interceptor which retrieves a bearer token from the redux store and attaches it to the request, but the store subscription indeed never completes... The `take(1)` should be placed there...

Comment: that explains. thanks for sharing! ;) /PS. `take(1)` or `first()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am forced to answer my own question, since I have found the answer. The problem stems from an interceptor I use, which is the hidden variable in this picture.

My application uses `ngrx` for redux store management. And my interceptor taps the store to obtain an authorization token.

Here's my interceptor code:

```js
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private store: Store<fromStore.State>,
    private route: Router) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpSentEvent
    | HttpHeaderResponse
    | HttpProgressEvent
    | HttpResponse<any>
    | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
    const rc = this.store.select(x => x.main.token).pipe(
      take(1), // <--- This is where the take(1) was needed
      switchMap(r => {
        const req2 = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${r}`
          }
        });
        return next.handle(req2);
      }));
      return rc;
  }
}
```

As you can see, without that `take(1)` up there, the request which is modified by the interceptor actually never completes, because the store subscription never completes.

Hope this obscure case helps someone :)

Comment: Not as obscure as you thought. :) Here I am, five years later, with a similar issue. 
`const upload$ = this.context$.pipe(map(ctx => ctx.id), switchMap(id => this.fileService.upload(formData, id)));`
I needed a promise that **has to be resolved after the file is uploaded**, from this observable and `lastValueFrom(upload$)` resolves the promise **only when the observable completes**.

But alas, my observable never completed due to the this.context$.

I needed take(1) before the map() and your answer was very useful for me to find the problem.